# Can I delete the Guest account but have two acount on my Samsung Tab

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-tab, accounts, delete

I will delete the Guest account but i would keep two users (Primary and a limited account). when i must choose, i will see only the two users and not three with the gest user.

It's possible ?

thanks

(i'm on a Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 8.0 - root)